# Rewriting Not In Sub-Select as Join for Propel

Tags: sql, join, symfony1, propel

Given the following schema:

```
person:
  id: ~
group:
  id: ~
group_membership:
  person_id: ~
  group_id: ~
```

I am attempting to find members not within a certain group using Propel's Criteria, which the following SQL will do:

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT person_id FROM group_membership
  WHERE group_id = 1
);
```

Unfortunately, Propel doesn't support sub-selects. It's possible to perform the sub-select first and pass it directly as an array, but I would rather do it in one call. I found [this article](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/75), which suggests using a custom criteria or converting it to a join.

Is it possible to convert the above SQL to a single Join with no nested selects?

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? MySQL?

Comment: @cularis Yes, MySQL. It would be translated to Criteria in Propel, anyway, so shouldn't matter too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be a substitute for the sub-query

```
SELECT *
FROM person
LEFT OUTER JOIN group_membership
  ON person.id = group_membership.person_id
   AND group_id = 1
WHERE group_membership.person_id is null
;
```

Rows returned where the `person_id` is null indicate where rows exist in `person` but not in `group_membership`

Comment: Thank you. That was just what I was looking for. I hadn't considered a left join.

Comment: I'd like to add, for anyone attempting a join with multiple criteria in Propel, see this link: http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2007/05/12/left-joins-with-multiple-conditions-using-propel-criteria/.