# Use of Propel's addMultipleJoin

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

Following on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877226/rewriting-not-in-sub-select-as-join-for-propel) about sub-selects, I have an SQL statement with multiple criteria on the join, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM person
LEFT OUTER JOIN group_membership
  ON person.id = group_membership.person_id
  AND group_id = 1
WHERE group_membership.person_id is null;
```

Unfortunately, Propel, the ORM I am using with Symfony, doesn't seem very adept using multiple joins, and previous people have tried to [hack criteria together](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2007/05/12/left-joins-with-multiple-conditions-using-propel-criteria/) to achieve results. Doing this confused Propel, and it started using CROSS JOINs. From what I've [read](http://groups.google.com/group/propel-users/tree/browse_frm/thread/28909085557558cf/722483894dabd83f?_done=%2Fgroup%2Fpropel-users%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F28909085557558cf%2F722483894dabd83f%3Ftvc%3D1%26&tvc=1), this was because Propel couldn't recognise the field ID of the second parameter:

```
$criteria->addJoin(self::ID, GroupMembershipPeer::PERSON_ID . ' AND ' .
    GroupMembershipPeer::GROUP_ID . '=' . $group_id,
    Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
```

I then found the [addMultipleJoin()](http://www.propelorm.org/attachment/ticket/167/propel-addmultiplejoin-patch.diff) method for Propel 1.4, which appears to work to some extent. I don't entirely understand it, or how I might call it to get what I desire:

```
$criteria->addMultipleJoin(array(
  array(
    'left' => self::ID,
    'right' => GroupMembershipPeer::PERSON_ID,
    'operator' => Criteria::EQUAL
  ),  
  array(
    'left' => GroupMembershipPeer::GROUP_ID,
    'right' => $group_id,
    'operator' => Criteria::EQUAL
  ),  
), Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
```

This results in some strange SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM `person` CROSS JOIN `group_membership` LEFT JOIN ON (= AND =) WHERE person.ID IN (3,5,17) AND group_membership.PERSON_ID IS NULL LIMIT 10
```

And PHP is throwing some strange errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /path/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/util/Criteria.php on line 675
```

Does anyone know whether it is myself or Propel doing something wrong, and how I might fix it, or accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong, but why are you didn't use something like this:

```
$c->addJoin(array(self::ID, GroupMembershipPeer::GROUP_ID), array(GroupMembershipPeer::PERSON_ID, $group_id) );
```

Criteria supports multiple join conditions since Propel 1.3. [Criteria doc](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.3/Criteria)